# How do i store output of the pipeline into an array

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have a scenario where I am getting required data that data need to be put into an array. Once data put into an array using echo it should be printed

```
v=`cat $FILE | rev | cut -d'|' -f4- | rev | cut -d'|' -f2- | sed 's/|/ /g'`
```

output it give :

```
123.23 3453.234
```

This output fecthing in an array "arraydemo"

```
mapfile -t arraydemo < echo "$v"
```

when I `echo arraydemo` its not printing anything .. showing 
error like this : echo: No such file or directory

```
echo "${arraydemo[@]}"
```

**This is how the output is script is running not printing data for** `echo "${arraydemo[@]}"`

```
+ FILE=demo.txt
++ cat demo.txt
++ rev
++ cut '-d|' -f4-
++ rev
++ cut '-d|' -f2-
++ sed 's/|/ /g'
+ var='16.84 15.24'
+ mapfile -t arraydemo

echo ''
```

Comment: `mapfile` does not produce any output that you can display. If you manage to put the data into the array (by using `<<<"$v"` in place of `echo "$v"`), you would get the same output from `echo "${arraydemo[@]}"` that you get from your pipeline. It would therefore be better to use the question title "How do i store output of the pipeline into an array" or something similar, of which there are already many variations on this site.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ a="1234 5678"

$ mapfile -t arraydemo < <(echo "${a}")

$ echo "${arraydemo[@]}"
1234 5678
```

Comment: `mapfile -t arraydemo <<<"$a"` is safer and shorter.

Comment: @Kusalananda can you look at it question updated having some issue